# VS Code: python code blocks sent to interactive window not appended to history

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Code blocks and lines sent from a script to the Python Interactive window via Shift-Return are not added to the interactive window's history and therefore can not be retrieved via Cursor-Up and Cursor-Down. This makes switching between the two methods of interactive code execution tedious. Can this be changed?